# Model destroy returning undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm trying to destroy a model and I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when I call this.model.destroy({options})

My model is like this:

```
    window.CompanyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('CompanyModel:initialized');
        },

        parse: function(response, options) {
            return response;
        },

    });
```

Collection:

```
    window.CompaniesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: window.CompanyModel,

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('CompaniesCollection:initialized');
        },  
    });
```

View:

```
    window.CompaniesView = Backbone.View.extend({
         initialize : function() {
             console.log('CompaniesView:initialized');
             this.companies = new CompaniesCollection();
             this.companies.url = function(id) {
                 return '../src/rest/administration/companies/companies';
             };
             this.company = new CompanyModel();
         },
         [...more code...]
         confirmDeleteForm : function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();

             var company_id = $('#company_existing').val();
             var self=this;
             this.company = this.companies.where({'company_id':company_id});

             this.company.destroy({
                 wait: true,
                 success: function(model, response) {
                     console.log('deleted');
                     $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                     self.cleanForm();
                     self.getCompanies();
                 },
                 error: function(model, response) {
                     console.log('error');
                     console.log(model);
                     console.log(response);
                     console.log(options);
                     if (response.status == 500) {
                        self.showErrorMessage('Se produjo un error en el servidor', 'ERROR');
                     } else {
                        self.showErrorMessage(response.responseText, 'ATENCION');
                     }
                }
           });

       },
```

Any help would be appreciated.

REgards, LN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.companies.where` returns an array, from the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where):

> **where** `collection.where(attributes)`
>
> Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed **attributes**.

That means that this:

```
this.company = this.companies.where({'company_id':company_id});
```

leaves an array in `this.company` and arrays don't have `destroy` methods.

If there is only one entry in `this.companies` that matches `{company_id: company_id}` then you could say:

```
this.company = this.companies.where({'company_id':company_id})[0];
// -----------------------------------------------------------^^^
```

or you could use [`findWhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere):

> **findWhere** `collection.findWhere(attributes)`
>
> Just like *where*, but directly returns only the first model in the collection that matches the passed **attributes**.

and say:

```
this.company = this.companies.findWhere({'company_id':company_id});
```

If that's the case then your `company_id` attribute is probably really the unique identifier for companies and then you might want to set the [`idAttribute`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute) in your model to `company_id`:

```
window.CompanyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'company_id',
    //...
```

so that you could use [`Collection#get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) to find it without searching.